# Multiple updates in MongoDB using java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am seeing several others questions but any of this solves my problem.

How Can I do this:

```
UPDATE table SET fiel1 = 'a', field2 = 'b', field3 = 'c' WHERE id='111'
```

in `MongoDB` using java driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you need to understand how the Mongo shell script should look like.
Your SQL-like query would translate into the following:

```
db.table.update({id : '111'},{$set : {fiel1 : 'a', field2 : 'b', field3 : 'c'}})
```

Using the Java driver, you will need something like the following:

```
//obtain the collection object:
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("table"); //I assume you create your DB-typed db object before

//query DB Object
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("id", "111");

//nested DB Object of update object
DBObject setObj = new BasicDBObject();
setObj.put("fiel1", "a");
setObj.put("field2", "b");
setObj.put("field3", "c");

//update DB Object
DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", setObj);

coll.update(query, update);
```

Comment: thanks for you help, but with this code I have an error in this line: `coll.update(query, update);`

Comment: thanks for you help, it works and I understand how the Mongo shell script should look like :)